# problems in listing and getting file names using directory_iterator with C++ boost library

Tags: c++, boost

I am trying to use the directory iterator from the boost library and i want to make a loop where I iterate through a directory and put the files names in a variable, i could use the leaf() function before, but now it is deprecated. I can't use path().filename() and even can use the native() and string() on this because the C compiler gives me errors. How can I fix this code below?

```
boost::filesystem::directory_iterator end_iter;
for (boost::filesystem::directory_iterator file(dir);file != end_iter;++file)
{
        /*check if file is image */ 
        string fileName=file->path().filename().native(); //the error happens here
        // i can use path().filename().string() either
        boost::match_results<string::const_iterator> what;
        if (0 == boost::regex_search(fileName, what, e, boost::match_default)) 
        {
            continue;
        };
...
```

thank you.

Comment: posting the error from your compiler might be useful

Comment: Thanks for yor reply. The error is /usr/bin/ld: /tmp/cclbmY0q.o: undefined reference to symbol '_ZN5boost6system15system_categoryEv'
/usr/bin/ld: note: '_ZN5boost6system15system_categoryEv' is defined in DSO /usr/lib/libboost_system.so.1.49.0 so try to add it to linker's command line
/usr/lib/libboost_system.so.1.49.0: could not read symbols: invalid operation

Comment: "Because the **C** compiler gives me errors." I think I found your problem ;)

Comment: have you tried to do what it says? i.e. add -lboost_system to your linker flags (potentially -lboost_filesystem too if it's not already there)?

Comment: @Casey: sorry, it's a c++ compiler.

Comment: @rectummelancolique, my makefile has these flags, my makefile has the following code:

CC = g++
CFLAGS = -g -Wall -Os -I./  
LDFLAGS = -Wall 
LIBS = -lboost_regex -lboost_filesystem -lpng -lm


spam: spam.cpp tspam12.o  auxiliary.o  ${LIBS}
 g++ -o spam ${CFLAGS} ${LDFLAGS} spam.cpp tspam12.o auxiliary.o ${LIBS}

.cpp.o:
 g++ -c -o $@ $< ${CFLAGS}

clean:
 rm -f *.o *~. Thank you again.

Comment: Add `-lboost_system` in there after `-lboost_filesystem` as @rectummelancolique suggests.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is solved after adding -lboost_system after -lboost_filesystem in makefile, as suggested by @Casey and @rectummelancolique.